# R filter produces NAs

Tags: r, na

I see posts on how the filter() function can deal with NAs, but I have the opposite problem.

I have a fully complete dataset that I process through a long algorithm.  One piece of that algorithm is a series of FIR filters.  After going through the filters, SOMETIMES my data comes back with NAs at the beginning and end.  They are not padding the original dimensions- they "replace" the values that would have otherwise come out of the filter.

I've come up with a couple of hacks to remove the NAs after they are created, but I'm wondering if I can prevent the NAs from showing up in the first place?

```
set.seed(500)
xoff <- sample(-70:70, 8200, replace=TRUE)
filt <- c(-75, -98, -130, -174, -233, -312, -412, -524, -611, -574, -246,  485, 1503, 2545, 3446, 4174, 4749, 5189, 5502, 5689, 5750, 5689, 5502, 5189, 4749, 4174, 3446, 2545, 1503,  485, -246, -574, -611, -524, -412, -312, -233, -174, -130,  -98,  -75)
xs = filter(xoff,filt)
```

40 NAs are returned.  20 at head, 20 at the tail.

```
sum(is.na(xs)==TRUE)
head(xs, n=21)
tail(xs, n=21)
```

The length of the original data and the filtered vector are identical.

```
length(xoff)==length(xs)
```

Another filter I use sometimes produces 20 NAs, 10 at the head, 10 at the tail.  So it is filter dependent.

Things I've thought about:
-Is the length of the data indivisible by the length of the filter? *No, the filter is length=41, and the data is length=8200.  8200/41 = 200.*
-Unlike a moving average which would need n observations prior to starting the smooth, this FIR filter provides the filter values and doesn't rely on prior observations.

so, any help debugging this is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: what do you try to achieve? Filter is also base R and take as first argument a function.

Comment: I'm using the filter function in base R, and am providing a vector as the first argument and the FIR filter values as the second argument. FIR filters are used to help pull out the signal from the noise.

Comment: Filter helps to take the element on the vector filling up a condition described in the function ...it does not take two vectors ...

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel `stats::filter`, which is what OP seems to be using, does takes a timeseries (which could be a vector) and a `filter` argument which is "a vector of filter coefficients...". So it does take two vectors. There's no `dplyr` here.

Comment: @user2573355 perhaps you're looking for the `circular = T` option (which assumes your data is circular, the last value is adjacent to the first)?